# sudo apt-get update fails

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and it worked fine for months now. yesterday I encountered this issue. When I update using GUI it says to check my internet connection. then I tried in terminal and it shows the following:

```
Hit:4 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Hit:6 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Get:1 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease [611 kB]            
Get:2 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [611 kB]    
Get:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [611 kB]  
Get:5 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [611 kB]   
Hit:7 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Err:1 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                     
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:2 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease             
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:3 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease           
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Err:5 http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease            
  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
Hit:8 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal InRelease                      
Reading package lists... Done
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease' is no longer signed.
E: Failed to fetch http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: Failed to fetch http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Clearsigned file isn't valid, got 'NOSPLIT' (does the network require authentication?)
E: The repository 'http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Can sombody please help me to fix this issue. Thank you.

Comment: `http://ro-mirrors.evowise.com` : is there any reason you are using this particular mirror?  I don't see anything at this address.  Can you post your `/etc/apt/sources.list`?

Comment: Are you using a proxy?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this specific mirror does not exist anymore. To change the mirror used for updates:

1. Launch "Software Update"
2. Go to "Settings..."
3. Go to the first tab named "Ubuntu Software"
4. In the dropdown "Download from" choose another mirror